# How to save an image into the separate folder in public external storage in the app targeting Android Q?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-external-storage, android-10.0, android-storage

getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type) has been deprecated and doesn't give access to public external storage if the app targeting Android Q. As alternative documentation suggests using MediaStore.

For Android, Q image can be saved into the separate folder "Custom_Directory", which is defined in MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH in a next way:

```
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "name")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis())
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "${Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES}/Custom_Directory/")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
}

val externalUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
val imageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(externalUri, values)
if (imageUri != null) {
    context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri).use { out ->
        bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
    }
    values.clear()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
    context.contentResolver.update(imageUri, values, null, null)
}
```

Unfortunately, this code requires API Build.VERSION_CODES.Q beacause MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH available only for Android Q and above. It is possible to save an image into Pictures directory in a next way for devices with SDK level lower than Q:

```
val values = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "name")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis())
}

val externalUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
val imageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(externalUri, values)
if (imageUri != null) {
    context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri).use { out ->
        bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
    }
```

But I didn't manage to find a way how to create a separate folder in the gallery. Again, getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type) can't be used.

I would appreciate your ideas. Please correct me if I'm going in a totally wrong direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187727  See Answer.

Comment: The subject of your post askes for code for Q. But what you really want is code for versions lower that Q.

Comment: Add something like: `String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/Custom_Directory/" + displayName;

     contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path); `

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for help. Unfortunately, `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`  can't be used. From documentation:

``@deprecated To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external
                  storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets
                  {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#Q}, the path returned
                  from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps.``

Comment: Of course you can use it. As that code will only be used if your app runs on a device below Q. There it works. It will not work on a Q device. But for Q you had already your code. Again: your subject is wrong. You did not need code for Q but for below Q.